# DockerHubのアカウントにログインできない。 FATA[0072] Error response from daemon: </html>

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Ubuntu上にDockerの環境構築をしていた時にエラーが発生しました。
`sudo docker run hello-world` は実行できたのですが、DockerHubのアカウントにログインしようとすると、エラーが発生してしまいます。

何か解決策や参考になりそうな物はありますでしょうか？
どなたか、お力添えをお願い致します。

以下が発生したエラーです。
(全て正しく入力しても永遠と同じエラー)

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo docker login
Username: 
Password:
Email:
FATA[0072] Error response from daemon: </html>
```

実行環境(Dockerのバージョン)

```
sudo apt install -y docker.io

docker -v
⇒Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2
```

追記
下記リンクを見ながら試してみたのですが、エラーは変わらずでした。

[DockerHubへのdocker loginが出来なかった場合の対処 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/developer-kikikaikai/items/03131dd1a9ac2b99e340)

実行したコード

```
sudo apt install gnupg2 pass
```

この返ってきてるのがhtmlの閉じタグってのが不明なんですよね…

Answer (score 1):

dockerのversionが古いことが原因です。
https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/fyfexo/fata0015_error_response_from_daemon_html_docker/

dockerをupgradeして再度試してください。
どのようにしてdockerをinstallしたかによってupgrade方法が変わりますが、以下一例です。
[https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#:~:text=To%20upgrade%20Docker%20Engine%2C%20first,version%20you%20want%20to%20install](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#:%7E:text=To%20upgrade%20Docker%20Engine%2C%20first,version%20you%20want%20to%20install).